# Calculating a p-value when H0 is an inequality

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing

I've seen it explained several times[1] on this site that with $H_1: \theta > a$, then the correct form for the null hypothesis is $H_0: \theta \leq a$. But how can I use this $H_0$ to calculate a $p$-value?

For example, consider a random variable $X \sim N(\mu,1)$. I want to test $H_1: \mu > 0$. With $H_0: \mu = 0$ it is easy, since assuming $H_0$ allows me to calculate probabilities with the $N(0,1)$ distribution. But with $H_0: \mu \leq 0$, how does assuming $H_0$ enable me to calculate a probability? How can I calculate a $p$-value without first assuming a value for $\mu$ rather than an interval?

[1] For example: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/177798

Comment: In such contexts, the null hypothesis contains an equal sign--whether as $=, \le,$ or $\ge.$ Using the value on the RHS of the equal sign gives you then 'null distribution' used to find the P-value.

Comment: @BruceET I take again the example with $X\sim N(\mu,1)$. Let's say I observe a sample with mean $\bar x > 0$. I can calculate the probability of a sample with mean $\bar x$ or more extreme, assuming that $\mu = 0$. This is not the same as the probability assuming $H_0$, but it is an upper bound for this probability, and we are content with using an upper bound to reach a conclusion in the test. Did I get it right?

Answer (score 0):

You are wanting to find the size of a test. For non simple hypotheses this is defined as $\text{sup}_{\theta \in H_0} W(\theta)$ where $W(\theta)$ is the power function: $W(\theta)=\mathbb{P}(\text{reject} H_0 | \theta)$

Comment: What you have written is the size of a test.